# improper training result dlib

Tags: dlib

[image: left landmark markings. right detection results]

i'm trying to train train_shape_predictor_ex for detecting following image in indian bill. i'm using 34 different images both clicked and scanned.
model is trained succesfully with

```
taining error = 0
testing error = 0.35468-6
```

i have tried changing oversampling parameter from 300 to 12000
but still same results.
what am i doing wrong?

drawing code - from image loading to drawing step:

```
    image_window win;

    frontal_face_detector detector = get_frontal_face_detector();
    shape_predictor pose_model;
    deserialize("sp.dat") >> pose_model;

    while (!win.is_closed())
    {
        cv::Mat temp;
        cap >> temp;


        cv_image<bgr_pixel> cimg(temp);

        std::vector<rectangle> faces = detector(cimg);

        std::vector<full_object_detection> shapes;
        for (unsigned long i = 0; i < faces.size(); ++i)
        {
            full_object_detection shape = pose_model(cimg, faces[i]);
            std::vector<rectangle> dets = detector(cimg);

            shapes.push_back(pose_model(cimg, faces[i]));

            win.clear_overlay();
            win.set_image(cimg);
            win.add_overlay(dets, rgb_pixel(255, 0, 0));
            win.add_overlay(render_face_detections(shapes));
       }
    }
```

Comment: please improve your question to answer this questions: right sample image is one from training dataset? every image sample from training dataset gives incorrect result? where is face bounding box on right sample? how many landmark points? does each point have the same meaning on each sample? where is ear on the right sample? what are shape_predictor training parameters?

Comment: There are total 14 points in all. All the images with training set give the same error in detection. Points are marked correct i have cross checked several times and even 0 training error possibly means that the points are correct. The bounding box is not appearing actually some points pixel position when i detect via face_landmark_detection is out of the picture i.e more pixels then there are actually in the image

Comment: Ear just isnt visible in the image uploaded. But the image is infact a complete scanned bill. Just that both images were to large to fit in at the same time on screem so i just snipped it that way

Comment: Any suggestions you have? Id try them all. I have trained previously on several datasets and it worked fine all the time. But some issue possibly less points? Or Less Sample s? Or need to change any of three training parameters? Some issue that interlocular distance part might be causing in the training?

Comment: Your training dataset should have face bounding boxes. How did you get them? Hand-drawn? When you are trying to test shape predictor, how do you get face bounding box? By frontal_face detector?

Comment: I draw face bounding box by imglab tool. Have tried detector for frontal_face generated bounding box. Ill get ti you shortly fo

Comment: For it. Just that pixel position was outside the image boundries that was my first concern

Comment: So face bounding boxes used for training are made not the same way as face bounding boxes used for testing. This is your main error i think

Comment: No. Both testing and trainjng boxes are made by imglab

Comment: publish your drawing code - from image loading to drawing step

Comment: have updated the question with code. kindly have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see now - you are trying to train custom shape_predictor that will only have 14 points while using Dlib's `render_face_detections` function that require Dlib's face shape that has 68 points. `render_face_detections` will not draw your shape correctly and should throw an exception.

To make your shape prediction work, please ensure that you follow this conditions:

1. **The meaning of each point should be the same on each image**. Do not put point #0 on ear on first image and #0 on the tip of nose on the second image
2. **Object bounding box should not be hand-drawn** if you have small dataset. If you use face detector for testing shape predictor - ensure that your training/testing images bounding boxes are made by detecting face with the same face detector. Yes, you can hand-draw whis bounding boxes, but please make sure that they have the same size and position as if they will be detected. **The way how you put box on the training set should be identical the way how you will get it in a future.**
3. **There is no requirement to fit all points inside face bounding box**. Really it can have any size and position, even static 10x10 box for each face on the tip of nose (or full bill rect) will work - but you should have enough training samples.  And follow previous condition
4. **Use as many images as possible**. 34 images is not enough for training shape predictor - if will simply remember them in its internal memory and will not work in a future. Dlib's shape predictor is trained with about 2-3k images.
5. **You can generate new images by distorting original ones** - scale, resize, add noise...
6. **Do not use Dlib's testing and drawing functions** if your shape predictor does not have 68 points with the same meaning as dlib's face shape predictor. You can use its source code and make your functions as you need

Comment: Except second and sixth point i have done it all. I got the sixt one too and will try it.

Comment: But im unable to understand second one. I got that you mean to have a box of same pixel area but same position! I'm unable to get that. Could you please elaborate on that

Comment: And how come the box could have same size if a resize the same image. What i gather from that is that you i just need to have same pixel area of box on all images with at centre a same landmark point. It doesn't matter whether the box bounds other landmarks or not.

Comment: And one more point though render_face_detctions will not draw shape correctly but still it should define pixel position accurately as i have also trained ibug dataset for 194 points and pixel position of all points is accurate just that the code need to be modified to adjoin lines correctly

Comment: about #2 - you can 1. load dataset. 2. iterate all images 3. redetect face and change rectangle position according to detected one. 4. use updated dataset to training. about resizing - when you resize image and detect face on it - detected rect will be resized too based on new image size

Comment: Ok i got it all now. With redetect face you mean to re mark the landmarks again?

Comment: What do you mean by redetect face?

Comment: training dataset has full_object_detection's inside. f.o.d has "rect". 1. load image. 2. run detector(img). 3. updae "rect" with the output of detector. 4. train

Comment: Ok got it :-p thanks sir. I'll let you know shortly about the results