# How can I train shape predictor to track pupil of eyes using dlib?

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, training-data, dlib, eye-tracking

It would be really useful if I could train the model to track pupil of eyes. Is it possible to do that ? If it is possible, how can I train shape predictor to track pupil of eyes using dlib?

Comment: create image dataset and train shape predictor. some details here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39953755/improper-training-result-dlib